# how to set focus to textfield after tab or alertview popup iphone?

Tags: iphone

i have to validate on length of text .
so, on Editing Did End event i  give alert if length exceed.
but it lost the focus form text field.
how can i set focus back to that same text field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set tag 11(any ) and set delegate self to that alert view and write below alert view delage method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag==11) 
    {
        [_textObj becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do like below, in your alert response callback,

```
[urTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're losing focus because you're showing alert in you DidEndEditing delegate method of your textField. If you want to keep the textField editable after you dismiss the alert which pops up you can use the delegate method of UIAlertView and in that method you can make your textField editable again by `[textfield becomeFirstResponder]`
I hope I understood your problem correctly.